# how to call a all checkbox ids in select/deselect all checkbox in ror application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add select/deselect all checkbox (I tried click the select all and delete the records(all) in my table) in my ror application. If I click the Select all checkbox, all checkboxes in the table are not selected, at the same time delete method are also not called.

Here my Controller file:

```
def destroy
      @messages = Message.where(id: params[:message_ids])
      @messages.destroy_all
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I am using jquery code in index.html.erb file itself. Here it is:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Messages</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]",class: 'selectall' %></th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <%= form_tag messages_path, method: :delete do %>
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id%></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td class="edititem"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message)%></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= submit_tag :Delete,class: 'btn' %>
</br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
<script>
$('#selectall').click(function(event) {
  if (this.message_ids) {
    $(':checkbox').attr('message_ids', true);
  } else {
    $(':checkbox').attr('message_ids', false);
  }
});
</script>
```

I am a beginner, Please Help me to solve my issue....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(".selectall").click(function () {
    $('#my-table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectall').toggle(function(){
    $('#my-table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','checked');

},function(){
    $('#my-table tbody input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1=> provide a id (`id: 'select_all_messages'`)on which click trigger all checkbox checked.

2=> provide a common class on all checkbox of message which will be triggered on click `id: select_all_messages`

like =>

```
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ><%= check_box_tag "select_all",id: 'select_all_messages' %></th>
          <th>Content</th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <%= form_tag messages_path, method: :delete do %>
        <% @messages.each do |message| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%#= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id, class: 'check_uncheck_message'%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]",message.id,false, class: 'check_uncheck_message'%></td>
            <td><%= message.content %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
            <td class="edititem"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message)%></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %> 
      </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#select_all_messages").on('click', function () {
    $('.check_uncheck_message').prop('checked', this.checked);
    //$('.check_uncheck_message').prop("checked", true);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If I give a class for <td> all check boxes are defaultly ticked

Comment: @Priya, hmm thats not good approach, reason being, in future suppose if you have any checkbox with different purpose in that case this will also be ticked. that is why, use id and class very specifically for its respective purpose. and that is why i have suggested to give a seperate id for you all select checkbox as above and a common class for all message check box which is wraped over you each do loop. hope fully you understood what i meant to say, anyway i think this the same problem that i helped you before. :), please let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @Priya after all either you will provide a common class for <td> or for `<%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]"...>` which is almost same, because it is inside each do block of message_id chekbox, however i'll suggest you to provide id class for checkbox , but not for table attributes.

Comment: @Priya feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you as well as for future searchers. :)

Comment: @Priya does this answer not help you? please let me know incase you have any doubt

Comment: @Priya are you still facing this problem. please let me know?

Comment: @ Gabbar Thanks for ur explanation and sorry for delayed reply, I understood your explanation , If I give the class for <td> or for <%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]"...> means  all boxes ticked default when I run the server, but what my need is When I click the select_all checkbox then only all checkboxes should be selected. Would u pls clarify my doubt

Comment: @Priya HI, i understood your doubt, actually by default checkbox is checked so you would need to provide one extra parameter `false` to make it unchecked by default, as i have also modified the answer, please have a look the answer, and let me know if you have any other doubt. thanks :)

Comment: @ Gabbar Now the default checked is become unchecked, but What I actually need means, I give a over all check box (<th ><%= check_box_tag "select_all",id: 'select_all_messages' %></th>) If I click that check box, It should be checked all the check boxes in the row of the table (like in gmail click the select all to delete the mails) like wise I want. Thanks :)

Comment: @Priya, Hi priya , can you check the `<script>` block code, that code is to check all table's checkbox on click `(<th ><%= check_box_tag "select_all",id: 'select_all_messages' %></th>) ` as this checkbox has been binded with `on click` event, please have a look at that script block. thanks :)

Comment: @ Gabbar Not Yet :( I am confused with this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168735/discussion-between-gabbar-and-priya).